# PhpStorm autocompletion in traits

Tags: php, phpstorm, traits

I have a trait that must always be mixed in to a subclass of `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. PhpStorm doesn't know this. Is there anything I can do to get PhpStorm to autocomplete and "typecheck" things like `assertNull` inside the trait?

```
<?php
trait MyTestUtils
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $this->assertNu // autocomplete?
    }
}
```

The best I could come up with so far is putting the following in each method:

```
/** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase|MyTestUtils $this */
```

But this is repetitive and doesn't understand protected memebers. Is there a better option?

Comment: Not ATM -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16368 (or similar: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=trait )

Comment: Have you found a soloution yet? `/** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase|MyTestUtils $this */
` does not work for me.

Answer (score 11):

Besides using the php docblock to document `$this`, the only other way I'm aware of, which also, arguably makes your trait more "safe" anyway, is to define abstract methods on the trait itself, e.g.:

```
 trait F {

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    abstract public function Foo();

    /**
     * @return self
     */
    abstract public function Bar();
}

abstract class Bar {
    use F;

    /**
     * @return bool|string[]
     */
    public function Baz () {
        if ($this->Bar()) {
            return $this->Foo();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome. In this way you declare a strong dependency that exists inside trait methods.

Comment: That's awesome, now client explicitly knows my trait dependencies

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE:** Since PhpStorm 2016.1.2 (build `145.1616`) autocompletion in traits works out-of-the-box. It is smart enough to figure out what classes use the trait, and then provide the autocompletion. Link to the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16368

**Previously replied with:**

You can use:

```
@method \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase assertTrue($condition, $message = '')
```

...in docblock of the trait itself, but the downside is that you'd need to put `@method` for each method that you'd like to have autocomplete for, which is not too bad if you're using a sane number of method calls in your trait. Or, "document" only those methods that you're using most often.

Comment: Documentation on the `@method` docblock https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that this is not a valid use-case for a PHP trait. Your trait, as written is not guaranteed to only be used on classes that extend \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. This introduces very tightly coupled code. The best practice of Traits is for them to be very loosely coupled and only be aware of their own contents.

I would instead recommend that you either:

1. create a subclass of \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase that your test cases that need this functionality can extend
2. create custom assertion classes. These can many times be used for doing groups of custom assertions.

Both techniques are detailed here: http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/extending-phpunit.html

These are the two recommended best practices for where to place helper methods such as these.

Comment: I think tightly coupled traits are entirely reasonable in scenarios like this. In a (mostly) dynamic language, we must (mostly) rely on documentation to guide the users of our abstractions anyway. Superclasses have the problem of being hard to compose arbitrarily due to single inheritance. Custom assertion classes are fine when you want to do assertions, but that's just one special case.